# Replace /v in C# string

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to replace "\v" in the string "Lapensee\v" with ""

```
string a = "Lapensee\v";
string b = a.Replace("\\v", "");
Console.WriteLine(b);

Output: Lapensee\v
```

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: Your question says /v but your code snippet says \v - which do you want to replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string a = "Lapensee\v";
string b = a.Replace("\v", ""); // You don't want the double \\ 
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Since you have \v in the string a, you should also replace it with \v.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant *either*:

```
string a = "Lapensee\\v";
```

or

```
string b = a.Replace("\v", "");
```

Comment: The data was imported from SQL and the string actually shows as Lapensee\v in the debugger. The vertical quote is causing another code block to fail and I need to remove it when the data is brought into the application.

Comment: In that case, it's the latter line of code you are interested in. :)

Answer (score 1):

\v in your string 'a', needs to be escaped too.  Else it will be interpreted as a vertical tab.